# MySQL REGEXP is not matching more than one word

Tags: mysql, regex

MySQL is not matching more than one word in REGEXP query. Will someone please assist?
For example, given a table with a field 'name' and a value listed

NAME:
"alpha bravo tango",
"Juliet bravo",
"delta tango",
"charlie oscar"

The following query returns nothing

```
 select * from t1 where name regexp '(alpha|bravo|delta){2,}';
```

The following query works

```
select * from t1 where name regexp '(alpha|bravo|delta){1,}';
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood correctly...

The regex '(alpha|bravo|delta){2,}' is looking for two or more consecutive occurrences of either of those words... so, alphaalpha, alphabravo, and bravodelta will match... but not alpha bravo. Are you looking for '((alpha|bravo|delta) ){2,}' or something like that?

Comment: I would use `((alpha|bravo|delta) ?){2,}` so that the final character doesn't have to be a space

Comment: I just realized something: the REGEXP function treats spaces as serious offenses. How do I make it ignore spaces? For example, when I pass in regexp '(alpha| bravo|delta){2,}', it works. (notice the space before bravo). How do I make it not mind spaces in a global sense? do I have to say regexp '( *alpha *| *bravo *| *delta *){2,}' or are there some more elegant options?